# Why is typeahead-js not working on Meteor but is working locally?

Tags: javascript, meteor, typeahead.js

My setup using typeahead-js is below. It's working very well locally with no problems. However, when I deploy to meteor, it's no longer working in that the datums are the same but the typeahead is not happening.

On Meteor.client:

```
Template.searchProfiles.rendered = function() {
    $('input#query').typeahead({
        name:'searchProfiles',
        local:searchProfilesDatums(),
    });
}

var searchProfilesDatums = function() {
    var datums = [];
    Profiles.find().forEach(function(profile) {
        tokens = profile.name.split(" ");
        datums.push({value:profile.name, nameRoute:profile.nameRoute, tokens:tokens});
    });
    return datums;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide the "name" attribute to a typeahead datum - [it caches the datum](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/typeahead.js#L21), and re-initialising any typeahead with another datum with the same name will re-use the datum - including local values.

If you're running remotely - the first datum may be initialised at a time when there's no data in the collection (eg waiting for the subscription), and subsequent datum's are ignored in favour of the cached one.

Possible solutions:

- Remove the datum name, prevents typeahead caching it
- Provide a unique name each time (bad idea, as they're all cached)
- Use IronRouter, with a before/ready hook for the required data/subscription
- Use a modified branch of typeahead that allows for computed callbacks (apparently [coming in version 0.10](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/220))

I'm currently using a [modified branch](https://github.com/brianmhunt/typeahead.js#dataset-with-compute-argument) which allows for computed values, but I have some of my own twists on it.

Comment: Thanks. This was a great answer. Solved the immediate issue and provides a good way of implementing a better solution